# customize the search functionality of openerp

Tags: python, postgresql, openerp-7

I am working with OpenERP and want to modify the search functionality of the project module.

When I search for the project name "test", openerp suggests:

```
"search project name for : test"
```

That's OK but i want to add more search options like:

```
"search description for: test", "search messages and notes for: test"
```

To do that I added fields in the search form like:

```
<field name="description" string="description"/>
<field name="messages" string="messages and notes"/>
```

After that, when searching I now see:

```
"search description for: test", "search messages and notes for: test"
```

Now I want to fetch those records from the database and print them.

"search for project" is working now.

Similar to this project for description and messages.

for more detail suppose i have two class

```
class project(osv.osv)
{
    __columns = {
        'complete_name': fields.function(_complete_name, string="Project Name", type='char', size=250),
     }
}

class task(osv.osv)
{
    __columns = {
         'x_description': fields.many2many('project.task', 'project_task','project_id','id' ,'x_description'),
     }
}
```

suppose i am in project module, and want to search project name which task contain description = "test description"

I don't know where I need to put the query and how?
any idea? thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand what the problem you're trying to solve here is. You seem to have described the solution to the problem in the title. Where's the question? What's the problem?

Comment: dscribed in description

Comment: *shrug*. I can't understand what you want. I don't really do OpenERP, so I can't really help you anyway.

Comment: don't worry thanks for reply. :)